# Changing Malvinas/Falkands (Argentina, South America) label in CartoDB?

Tags: carto, south-america, argentina

I'd like to know if there any way to change or hide the label of "Falklands Islands" in south Atlantic Ocean, South America, Argentina, in CartoDB.

I know CartoDB works with Open Street View.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the labels on the basemap, there's no option to customize them, as CartoDB creates the basemaps and then serves them with the style and data choosen.

CartoDB uses OSM data in order to create their own basemaps (Dark Matter and Positron).

If you don't want any labels at all, you can use the "Lite" basemaps that only include the geometries of the countries but not the layers.

Another workaround that you can follow is to use an external basemap that you like, as you can add any custom basemap with the CartoDB Editor UI.